# Express res.sendFile() with Query String

Tags: html, node.js, express, static

I have successfully implemented serving static files using res.sendFile() but it doesn't works if I add some querystring.

E.g. the below code works absolutely fine.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', '/index.html'));
```

But if I do this, it fails

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', '/index.html?id=' + req.params.id));

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', '/index.html?id=123'));
```

Then I get the below error

```
ENOENT, stat '/Users/krishnandu/Documents/Project/public/index.html?id=123'

404

Error: ENOENT, stat '/Users/krishnandu/Documents/Project/public/index.html?id=123'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: I think you should be using `res.render` instead and pass the parameter to the view template

Comment: @CodeBeginner Well I'm rendering a static HTML file instead of jade / ejs based template files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass query string parameters with `res.sendFile()`. You have to specify the file path as the 1st parameter in `res.sendFile()`

Syntax is :

```
res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])
```

So what you can do is,

1. Use the query string with a route, say **route1** (refer the below code)
2. Inside the GET method of **route1**, use `res.sendFile()`

   ```
   app.get('/route1',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', '/index.html'));
   });

   res.redirect('/route1?id=123');
   ```

See also [Express API documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) of [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) and [res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect).

Comment: How can I access `id` in `index.html`?

Comment: You would access from the frontend, i.e., window.location.search. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: This doesn't show how to add the query string to sendfile

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is to further add on to @Marie Sajan's answer by covering the question asked by @Sky in a comment.**

To access `id` in `index.html` after using @Marie Sajan's answer you can use normal client-side javascript. You could do something like this in `<script>` tags in your html file:

`var query = location.href.split("?")[1];`

This would get you a string such as "id=123&name=ted".
From here you can use javascript to get the value of `id`. The full code might look something like this:

```
var query = location.href.split("?")[1]; //A string of all parameters in the URL
var params = query.split("&"); //Turns the string into an array of parameters
var id; //To store the value of id

params.forEach((param, index) => {
    //This checks each key-value pair, in the format key=value, for the specific id key we want
    var key = param.split("=")[0]; //In id=123, this would be "id"
    var value = param.split("=")[1]; //In id=123, this would be "123" (as a String)
    if (key == "id") id = value;
});
```

Now the javascript variable `id` will contain the value "123".

If you were also looking for the values of more query parameters in addition to the `id` key, you would simply add more `if` statements inside the `forEach` to check for those specific keys.

In a link such as "http://google.com/?q=stack+overflow&id=123", this code would be able to get the value "123" of `id` when implemented as client-side javascript either directly in the HTML file in `<script>` tags, or in a separate client-side js file that is used by the HTML file. Note that @Marie Sajan's answer is entirely server-side code, while this code is what would be used on the client-side.

***This answer does not address the original question, it only adds further useful content to an accepted answer to the question based on the needs of viewers of this page.***

Comment: Instead of doing `var query = location.href.split("?")[1]`, you can also instead do `var query = location.search`. It has universal major browser support.